# Retaining an image's size when padding is added

Tags: html, css, image, padding

I am working on the week 2 final TReact project and am encountering difficulties when attempting to add padding around an image while retaining its size on page 7/19 of the quick help guide. Whenever I add padding, the image disappears or becomes too small. Here is the given HTML and CSS code:

HTML:

```
<div class="services">
  <div class="service">
    <span class="span-img__container"><img src="shield.svg" class="service__img" alt=""></span>
    <span class="span__container">
      <h3 class="service__header">Secure</h3>
      <p class="service__description">We strictly only deal with vendors that provide top notch security.</p>
    </span>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.services {
  padding-top: 64px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.service {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}

.service__header {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.service__img {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: -20px; /* The issue is here */
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.service__description {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 2;
  color: rgb(124 139 161);
}

.span-img__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 45px;
}

.span__container {
  margin: 8px 0 0 16px;
}
```

What can I do to add padding without affecting the image size?

Comment: What are you attempting to do? Adding padding to the image will push in the image by definition. Maybe you want to add a margin? Or maybe you should apply the padding to the `span-img__container`?

Answer (score 0):

In the service__img class, you can simply add `box-sizing: border-box`. This will make sure that the padding is added to the width and height of the image and the image doesn't increase in size.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I appreciate the help I played with the inspect element also got it sized correctly but now its overflowing my container. Again thanks .

Comment: Did you try adding box-sizing: border-box to the service_img class? Or after your comment, you can add this line to the container class. Hope it helps!